# Gulp watch task is not working when sass/js/html file is saved

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

I am trying to reload the browser when scss, HTML and js file is changed but when I run the `gulp watch` command it's not reloading the browser or can't see any css/js/html changes.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
// Requires the gulp-sass plugin
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss') // Gets all files ending with .scss in app/scss
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        },
    })
})

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series(['browserSync', 'sass']), function() {
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes shown here:

```js
gulp.task('browserSync', function(done) {         // done added here
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    },
  });
  done();                                          // done() called here
})

// gulp.task('watch', gulp.series(['browserSync', 'sass']), function() {
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('browserSync', 'sass', function () {       // see note below
  
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));

    // gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);

    gulp.watch("app/*.html", { events: 'all' }, function(cb) {
      browserSync.reload();
      cb();
    });

    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
}));                                                                       // added a )
```

`gulp.watch()` takes 2 arguments, not 3.  `gulp.series()` should include all the functions - including your anonymous function that contains the `watch` calls.  And lose the array brackets.

Comment: well, I am checking it

Comment: on first Html changes it's showing the changes but if I again change the html then I can't see the changes. I have to reload the page

Comment: WOW, it's Working fine :) So we need to use 2nd arg for the object, right?

Comment: I have one more question: when I run the `gulp watch` command it's locating me to http://localhost:3000/ that is loading index.html page. Now, If I create another HTML file then how can I reload that page automatically when I. make changes?

Answer (score 1):

With respect to [Mark's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64854402/1), just add `.on('change', browserSync.relod)` to the end of the desired watch if you want to see the live reload:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
// Requires the gulp-sass plugin
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss') // Gets all files ending with .scss in app/scss
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function (done) {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    },
  });
  done();
})

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('browserSync', 'sass', function () {
  gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
  gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}));
```