# Gulp is not comile sass file and reload the page

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

I have this code in my gulpfile.js file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
// Requires the gulp-sass plugin
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        },
    })
})

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss') // Gets all files ending with .scss in app/scss
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series(['browserSync', 'sass']), function() {
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
    // Reloads the browser whenever HTML or JS files change
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Now, when I run this command

```
gulp watch
```

It's open the **project** on browser **BUT**, when I do some changes on html, js or scss file **then** gulp **does not** compile the scss file and reloading the browser.

Can someone tell me what is the issues here?

Comment: Which version of gulp are you using?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your question  at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64853341/gulp-watch-task-is-not-working-when-sass-js-html-file-is-saved/64854402#64854402 (which I answered).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gulp watch task is not working when sass/js/html file is saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64853341/gulp-watch-task-is-not-working-when-sass-js-html-file-is-saved)

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan I am using 4

Comment: @Mark I am checking it :)

Comment: @Mark I have replied

Comment: @Shibbir, have a look at [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64854794/6174271)

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan Thanks a lot for your answer but I got the solution from Mark.